# dynamically add container with form to another container

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have created a `Panel` in which there is a `list` on the left side and right side there is a `container` you can see the picture below.

[image]

now when the `Fruits` item gets clicked i want to load a form on the right side , so far i have successfully captured the `itemtap` event in controller for list item because i am using MVC pattern.

```
onMenuTap:function(me, index, target, record, e, eOpts){


     // here i want to dynamically load the existing container 
     // which contains the form

    }
```

i have already created a form as follows , name of the file is `FruitForm.js` and i want to 
add this existing container into the right side of a container , how can i do that ?

```
Ext.define('market.view.FruitForm',{

    extend:'Ext.Container',
    xtype:'fruitform',
    requires:[
            'Ext.form.Panel'
        ],

    config:{

        items:[{

            xtype:'form',
            items:[{

                xtype:'fieldset',
                items:[{
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'notitle',
                            label: 'Title:'
                        }]


            }]


        }]


    }



});
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work:

```
(Add code to get right container).add({'xtype': 'fruitform'});
```

To get the container you might have to use something like:

```
this.query('#Container_itemId')[0];
```

Comment: i have added the `ref` of container which is on the right side and use the `this.getFreePanel().add({xtype:'fruitform'})` but i am getting error `Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget.form`

Comment: add the view to the app.js. Add it to the Ext.Application's "views" array.

Comment: form is not a valid xtype. hence the line that read: xtype:'form', is not valid. Change the xtype to a container or something else